# Web scraping JS content with Python (Yahoo Finance)

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am currently struggling with this page of Yahoo Finance : *https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/1B0.SI/history?period1=1426780800&period2=1489939200&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=split&frequency=1mo*

I would need to get the date and ratio of the stock split, but I dove into a json file in which I do not see any of these information!

I'm using the script mentionned here [How to understand this raw HTML of Yahoo! Finance when retrieving data using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631386/how-to-understand-this-raw-html-of-yahoo-finance-when-retrieving-data-using-pyt)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint as pp
import re
import json
import requests  

url='https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/1B0.SI/history?period1=1426780800&period2=1489939200&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=split&frequency=1mo'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
script = soup.find("script",text=re.compile("root.App.main")).text
data = json.loads(re.search("root.App.main\s+=\s+(\{.*\})", script).group(1))
stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]
pp(stores)
```

Please let me know if your have the idea where I can find it.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a module for Yahoo Finance if you want, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance

Comment: @AnthonyPradal Thank you, to be honest I did not know the API, but I don't see any method to get Stock Splits..
I would also like to solve this problem, it should be useful to me in other projects. 
For example, the solution cited here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445966/scraping-javascript-with-python-and-selenium-webdriver is really powerful in many cases, but in mine there is no such iFrame :(

Comment: Do you want the information displayed in the table with the dates Oct 11, 2016 and Feb 25, 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My surmise is that you can do this with **selenium**, thus.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/1B0.SI/history?period1=1426780800&period2=1489939200&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=split&frequency=1mo')
>>> driver.get('https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/1B0.SI/history?period1=1426780800&period2=1489939200&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=split&frequency=1mo')
>>> tableRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr')
>>> len(tableRows)
5
>>> tableRows[1].text
'Date Open High Low Close Adj close* Volume'
>>> tableRows[2].text
'Oct 11, 2016 2/1 Stock split'
>>> tableRows[3].text
'Feb 25, 2016 2/1 Stock split'
```

Notice especially that I had to load the page twice. The first load failed. You can learn how to deal with this contingency in the selenium documentation. (Use a `try-except` rather than an `asssert`.) The main difficulty one faces in scraping this page is that one cannot see the HTML. I made the assumption that the desired content would be in a table and that assumption proved correct.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. In conclusion, there is no tips to go over the blinded search of HTML tags?

Comment: You might be able to do that with a headless browser in this case but that proved unnecessary.

Comment: I've just learned of a way. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183736/beautifulsoup-does-not-returns-all-data/43191283#43191283.